# Did I install stunnel correctly?

Tags: ssl, tls, stunnel

Running Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit.

```
apt-get install build-essential -y
apt-get install libssl-dev -y
apt-get install wget -y
cd srv
wget https://www.stunnel.org/downloads/stunnel-5.23.tar.gz
tar -xzf stunnel-5.23.tar.gz
rm stunnel-5.23.tar.gz
cd stunnel-5.23
./configure
make
make install
rm -r stunnel-5.23
```

I can't seem to locate the `/etc/stunnel` directory?

Comment: Why did you not install stunnel from your distro's apt repository?

Comment: @EEAA It's running an older version 4.x something.

Comment: And there are features in 5.23 that you need?

Comment: Not exactly, but if you check the logs here: https://www.stunnel.org/sdf_ChangeLog.html You see quite a lot has happened since (bug fixes/security fixes)!

Comment: Security fixes are back-ported. Unless you need the features, **always** use your distribution's packages. For this reason, and many many others.

Comment: @EEAA Ahh is this so. I have learnt something useful today! However, it still bugs me why it doesn't state in the README or INSTALL file where the config file should reside.

Answer (score 2):

There is *MUCH* easier way using `apt-get`, refer to following:

[How To Set Up an SSL Tunnel Using Stunnel on Ubuntu | DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-ssl-tunnel-using-stunnel-on-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

If you compile your own package, then you need to put the configuration files in a location where the startup script you create/install will read.  A build from source of stunnel by default doesn't include any startup scripts.  It doesn't tell you want to do, because the assumption is that if you are building from source, you can figure that part out on your own.  You are completely on your own to make your own startup script, and place your config files wherever you like.

If you are using the Debian/Ubuntu packaged version of stunnel, then you place config files under `/etc/stunnel`, and the startup script will read all those in and start a daemon for each config.  See `/etc/default/stunnel` for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try /usr/local/etc.
Or maybe a find -type d would help.

Comment: Would you mind expanding a little on your answer, to help the OP (and future visitors) to more easily solve their problem?